# Bluetooth Software for Dell Inspiron One 2320

Tags: bluetooth, dell-inspiron

Where to download the bluetooth software for DELL Inspiron One 2320, as I accidentally deleted it and now the bluetooth is not working?

Comment: On Dell's support homepage, maybe? Have you tried looking already?

Comment: May be you are looking for this page of [Dell driver](http://search.ap.dell.com/results.aspx?c=in&l=en&s=dhs&cat=sup&cs=indhs1&k=dell+inspiron+one+2320&rpp=12&p=1&rf=all&nk=f&ira=False&~srd=False&ipsys=False&advsrch=False&~ck=tab).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the Dell support page for your model](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/entry?c=us), look under Inspiron Desktop on the right or enter your [service tag](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?docid=267748&~srd=true&sk=service%20tag&scat=sup) on the left

Answer (score 1):

The drivers are not on the right site. The part number for the Bluetooth WiFi combo was DW1702. [Download the drivers here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?c=us&s=dhs&cs=19&l=en&DriverId=R301705).